# Updatepanel and fancybox not working unless fancybox is opened twice

Tags: updatepanel, fancybox, repeater, custompaging

Ok I have a page being pulled through onto the fancybox popup,

(note: the paging works 100% on the page itself),

but when on the fancybox I attempt to page through the repeater and nothing happens.
I then close the popup and reopen it without refreshing the page, and paging now works?

I refresh the page then have to go through the process of opening the popup then trying to page through the repeater then close the popup then reopen it and the paging works again.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what maybe causing this? I've already attempted Change the 'body' to 'form' method's.

EDIT: It does manage 1 postback, then it freezes and if reopened works for more then 1 postback.

EDIT: I have found that when the update panel send the request and comes back it creates a secondary __VIEWSTATE object in the updatepanel.

Code for the page being called:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Search.aspx.cs"Inherits="AfricaCentre.Search" EnableEventValidation="false" EnableViewState="false" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/Scripts.js")  %>"></script>--%>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<!-- SEARCH -->
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        Hello
        <asp:Button Text="Test" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Link button calling the fancybox with script:

```
<a id="search" href="/Search" class="fancybox.ajax">SEARCH</a>
$("#search").fancybox(
            {
                type: 'ajax',
                autoSize: false,
                padding: 0,
                width: 800,
                height: 567,
                scrolling: 'no',
                openEffect: 'fade',
                openSpeed: 'slow',
                transitionIn: "elastic",
                transitionOut: "elastic",
                autoScale: false,
                hideOnContentClick: false,
                afterLoad: function () {
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: it's difficult to help if you don't provide any code or link with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just used an iframe to resolve my problem.